# How to run docker container with bash shell?

Tags: docker

It works with ubuntu image

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@00e6296d31d8:/#
```

However, when I try it with different image such as `vulnerables/web-dvwa`, it doesn't work anymore

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker run -it vulnerables/web-dvwa /bin/bash
[+] Starting mysql...
[ ok ] Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
[+] Starting apache
[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
. ok 
==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Sat Apr 03 11:54:24.321232 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 307] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 03 11:54:24.321280 2021] [core:notice] [pid 307] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==

id
whoami
```

There is no bash shell in this container

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
820d3a292b2c   vulnerables/web-dvwa   "/main.sh /bin/bash"   11 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds   80/tcp    upbeat_visvesvaraya
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the container with:

```
 docker exec -ti 820d3a292b2c bash
```

or:

```
 docker exec -ti upbeat_visvesvaraya bash
```

Answer (score 2):

That image you are trying to run i.e. `vulnerables/web-dvwa` contains `ENTRYPOINT ["/main.sh"]` which runs mysqld on startup. If you need a just a shell in that image you can override the main entry like so below ...

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash vulnerables/web-dvwa
```

OR if you want a shell on the running mysqld container, you can run it normally w/ out `-it` argument and then do the following to get a bash shell in the running container.

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```